# Is there a way to upload pdf file to laravel project using a jquery plugin?

Tags: laravel, file, pdf, upload

i have a laravel project where i create a record in my database,everything is set up correctly to upload a pdf file using the submit form, i have my form setup like this

```
<form action="{{ route('store') }}"  enctype="multipart/form-data" 
class=" " style="padding:1%,5%,1%,5%;" files="true">
</div>
<div class="file-field input-field col ">
  <div class="btn">
    <span  class="active">PACKING SLIP</span>
    <input type="file" name="paperwork">
  </div>
  <div class="file-path-wrapper">
    <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

in my controller i have tried with many methods to store the file uploaded from the 'paperwork' input but everything fails, either it says the 'file' is a string and i cannot use laravel's native file manipulation methods, i tried with codeguy/upload but i always get "directory doesn't exist", i have done the "Storage:link" and still haven't got the file uploaded, i tried storing it in "public/packingslips","resoruces/uploads/packingslip", it seems to me that the file picked from the html form is only the name of the file and no object is created.

my controller store method does not include any data validation for now i am focusing on getting the file upload working for now

```
  public function store(Request $request) {
     $shipment=new Shipment;
     $shipment->tracking=request('tracking');
     $shipment->PartNumber = request('PartNumber');
     $shipment->DateShipped=request('DateShipped');
     $shipment->QtyShipped=request('QtyShipped');
     $shipment->invoice=request('invoice');
     $fdate = request('DatesShipped');
     $fdate = Carbon::parse(request('DateShipped'));
     $tdate = Carbon::parse( today());
     $to = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:s:i', $fdate);
     $from = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:s:i', $tdate);
     $diff_in_days = $to->diffInDays($from);
     $shipment->age=$diff_in_days;
     $shipment->purchaseOrder=request('purchaseOrder');
     $shipment->location=request('location');
     $shipment->paperwork=request('paperwork');//this is were my file i supposed to be stored
     $shipment->VMIreceived=request('VMIreceived');
     $shipment->VMILRB=request('VMILRB');
     $shipment->VMIticketNumber=request('VMIticketNumber');
     $shipment->Description=request('Description');
     $shipment->Manufacturer=request('Manufacturer');
     $shipment->Lot=request('Lot');
     $shipment->save();

       return redirect()->route('index')
                        ->with('success','Shipment created successfully');

     }
```

any pointers? thanks in advance

Comment: i need to move the file to storage, but in the request there's no file only a string with the name

Comment: yes, this is one of the first methods i tried but i get error:"Call to a member function store() on null" because there is no object to move, only a string with the name of the file

Comment: GET Data
_token 
"uoBDC4aupTlYpyCzNxFzOeOE2DpRsHoAGEiVgHJI"
_method 
"POST"
tracking 
"1z128a0040"
PartNumber 
"wm010101"
DateShipped 
"2019-01-01"
QtyShipped 
"1"
invoice 
"11"
age 
""
PurchaseOrder 
"1111"
location 
"VMI"
paperwork 
"Portal_PEMPLEADO_14561771000.pdf"
VMIreceived 
""
VMIticketNumber 
""
VMILRB 
""
description 
""
manufacturer 
""
lot 
""
POST Data empty
Files empty
Cookies///it doesn't have  a file!!

Comment: GET Data
paperwork 
"label - 2019-09-03T075027.794.wmlabel"
_token 
"uoBDC4aupTlYpyCzNxFzOeOE2DpRsHoAGEiVgHJI"
POST Data empty
Files empty/// still files are empty

Comment: i mentioned a jquery plugin to trigger the file upload with the submit event